# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in Dynamic Web app JSP

Tags: java, sqlite, class, jsp

I am trying retrieve data from SQLLite DB in a Java Class.
This is the part of the web app that uses the Beans and Form processing" as per the tutorial  here:
*http://www.jsptut.com/forms.jsp*

I am getting a persistent error of java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC

I have added sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7.jar to the java classpath

This is my code:

```
   public int startConnection() {
         Connection c = null;
            try {
              Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
              c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
              System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
              System.exit(0);
              return CONNECTION_FAILURE;
            }
            System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
            return CONNECTION_SUCCESSFUL;
    }
```

This is the console output:

```
Jan 03, 2015 2:42:15 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:webapp01' did not find a matching property.
Jan 03, 2015 2:42:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
Jan 03, 2015 2:42:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Nov 3 2014 08:39:16 UTC
Jan 03, 2015 2:42:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.57.0
Jan 03, 2015 2:42:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Mac OS X
Jan 03, 2015 2:42:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.10
Jan 03, 2015 2:42:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86_64
Jan 03, 2015 2:42:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JAVA_HOME:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Jan 03, 2015 2:42:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_25-b17
Jan 03, 2015 2:42:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Jan 03, 2015 2:42:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/hadi/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Jan 03, 2015 2:42:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /Users/hadi/Documents/apache-tomcat-7.0.57
Jan 03, 2015 2:42:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/hadi/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Jan 03, 2015 2:42:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Users/hadi/Documents/apache-tomcat-7.0.57
Jan 03, 2015 2:42:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/Users/hadi/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
Jan 03, 2015 2:42:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Users/hadi/Documents/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/endorsed
Jan 03, 2015 2:42:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Jan 03, 2015 2:42:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/hadi/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
Jan 03, 2015 2:42:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 03, 2015 2:42:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 03, 2015 2:42:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1296 ms
Jan 03, 2015 2:42:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 03, 2015 2:42:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
Jan 03, 2015 2:42:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 03, 2015 2:42:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 03, 2015 2:42:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 913 ms
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
Jan 03, 2015 2:42:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

Please anyone solve this problem......Thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7.jar` to the *tomcat* class-path by moving it to `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`.

See the [Apache Tomcat 7 - Class Loader Howto](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) for an in-depth look at how the Tomcat class loader works. It reads, in part,

> System — This class loader is normally initialized from the contents of the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. All such classes are visible to both Tomcat internal classes, and to web applications. However, the standard Tomcat startup scripts (`$CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh` or `%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat`) totally ignore the contents of the `CLASSPATH` environment variable itself, and instead build the System class loader from ...